Is is possible to rewrite a prometheus metric type during scraping?
I have a prometheus endpoint that is exposing some metrics with TYPE untyped, I need to scrape those as type GAUGE.
I have look at the scrape_config,relabel_config, metric_relabel_config but it's not clear to me if there is a meta label/ special label / double underscore label that can be used to set the type of the metric.
Is there any way to rewrite a metric type during scraping?
